# Does the primary key of Web Service API in ML Studio expire?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

I deployed a web-service from an experiment in ML studio. I tested the API, and everything was working fine. I tested it in Postman. After 2 hours, I got an authentication error when I sent a request using the same API. So to resolve this, I republished my Web Service and got new authentication code, so the API is working fine for now. I have two questions:

1) Does the primary key automatically expire after a while or by signing out from ML studio? 
2) What is the application of the second key in ML Studio APIs? Where do we need the second key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Does the primary key automatically expire after a while or by signing out from ML studio?

I could not find any limit of the primary key in the office docs. Per my test, my primary key does not expire more than two hours or sign out from ML studio.

> 2) What is the application of the second key in ML Studio APIs? Where do we need the second key?

The second key is the same usage of the primary key, like a backup of the primary key. Also, the primary key equals the API key in the ML studio.